# HTML file extension working but PHP is not working

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, navbar

I don't knwow why php links are not working on my site.

I created a wordpress site but the link to other pages are not working. I thought it was a problem with wordpress. I created a site with .html and uploaded, it worked fine. I converted the same file to .php and uploaded but it will not work. When I click on the about page, it will load the url as https://www.mywebsite.com/about.php but the content will be that of index.php.

what can I do about this please.

`

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto ">
    <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home <span 
    class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="about.php">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="properties.php">Properties</a>
    </li>              
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="contacts.php">Contacts</a>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

`

Comment: Pleas show your code

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if I am incorrect and if I am understanding your question and what you’re trying to achieve. When you access your website example.com when someone clicks on links that you have i.e. about us, contact us, terms, privacy, login, signup, etc you want the file extension not to show i.e. example.com/about_us.html or example.com/login.php but show as example.com/about_us or example.com/login

Before you make any changes, make a copy of your .htaccess > once you have made a copy of your .htaccess file, download your .htaccess and open it up with a plain text editor like Notepad NOT word, or WordPad > you can enter this code in (see below) > then save and upload to your server > try to access your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.htm -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.htm


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

When someone types in a page that does not exist, and it automatically goes to your index page that’s because you need to change a small line of code from this

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

to this

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```